# Java search String(kmp)

Tags: java, string, search, knuth-morris-pratt

I want to search how many occurrences of a string(lets say a) are in a string b.
I thought of implementing Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm, but I prefer a built in java function. Is there any function like  this?  I want the function to be as with the lowest Complexity as possible since I use it many times.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Are you searching a small query inside a larger text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KMP algorithm is *not* part of the standard Java library, but it's easy enough to find implementations online, like [this one](http://www.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/fmi/logic/vboutchkova/sources/KMPMatch.java).

Answer (score 0):

This is part of a very old project I did. Might be good for inspirating but not sure if it is the fastest way.

Basiclly you use the Automaton function to create a state machine table. Then, you use the math function to check the occurences!

Automaton Param : pattern is the pattern you're looking for and alpha are all the caracters in that pattern (ex : pattern - aabba, alpha - ab)

My appologies for the french comments!

```
public Automaton(String pattern, char[] alpha){

    //declaration et initialisation
    _alpha = alpha;
    _pattern = pattern;
    int m = pattern.length();
    String Pqa = "";
    String Pk = "";

    //Initialisation du Map
    for(int map = 0; map < alpha.length ; map++){
        alphaMapc.put(alpha[map],alpha[map]);
        alphaMapNum.put(alpha[map],map);
    }

    tableau = new int[pattern.length()+1][alpha.length];

    // Algo d'apres le pseduo code et les notes
    for(int q=0 ; q <= m ; q++){            
        for( int j =0 ; j <  alpha.length ;  j++  ){
            Pqa = pattern.substring(0,q );
            Pqa += alpha[j];
            int k = Math.min(m+1, q+2);

            //Do while qui test Pq avec toutes le fins possibles
            do{
                k = k-1;
                Pk = pattern.substring(0, k);

            }while( k >0 && !(Pqa.endsWith(Pk)) );

            tableau[q][j] = k;
            System.out.print(k + " "); // TEST OUTPUT
        }
        System.out.println(); // TEST OUTPUT
    }



}

public int match(String string) {

    //Initialisation de letat et du compte
    int etat = 0;
    int compte = 0;

    for(int s = 0; s < string.length() ; s++){          
        char t = string.charAt(s);      

        //Acces en O(1)
        if(t == alphaMapc.get(t)) etat = tableau[etat][alphaMapNum.get(t)];

        //Si on atteint un etat final, on recommence a l'entree de la machine et on increment le compteur
        if(etat == 15){
            etat = 0;
            compte++;
        }
    }

    //Test
    System.out.println("Compte: " + compte);
    return compte;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Regards,
Erwald

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can simply use the `String.indexOf()` method.

It do not use the KMP algorithm. For short string it is good enough, but if you need performance and you intend to use with large string then is not a good choice.

However if you want a simple solution, here it is:

```
int n = 0, i = 0;
while (i < str.length() 
       && (i = str.indexOf("al", i)) != -1) {
  ++n;
  ++i;
}
System.out.println("n: " + n);
```

it counts all the occurrences of the substring.